# How to get the value for the given json and get result

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, encode

I am trying to get the result for the below query

```
$users = DB::select("SELECT FIND_IN_SET('l','a,b,c,d') as Res");
```

and while i do

return $users;

Here is my json

```
[{"Res":0}]
```

When i try to `decode` it, it shows me the error

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

When i `var_dump` i am getting as

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#773 (1) { ["Res"]=> int(0) } }
```

So, How can i get the result of the `'Res'` ?

Comment: Guessing you need to do $object[ 0 ]->res; since you have an array containing an object containing the string in 'res' property.

Comment: Please [edit] to add the full context of code that's running into these problems here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my question, please see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the error:

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, **array given**
```

That is, the result data is being returned as an array which based on your var_dump also contains your result object and subsequent data.

This should do it:

```
<?php
     $data = $users[0]->Res
     $decoded = json_decode($data);
```

Note that this is essentially just turning your JSON string into an object. You can use the second parameter to have it returned as an array if preferred:

```
<?php 
     $data = $users[0]->Res
     $decoded = json_decode($data, true);
```